# How to enable dark mode toggle button on any web browser without the help of a fancy (and possibly intrusive) extension?

Tags: browser, dark-mode

I'm using different web browsers on different OSs and I enjoy using dark mode wherever I can, through the OS level and the rest of native applications.

For web browsing experience, I always find myself installing third party extensions which I don't know if I can trust my personal web traffic with, and I wonder, is it possible to do this generically and simply such that it will work in any browser without relaying on 3rd party extensions?

How would you enable dark mode toggle button on any web browser without the help of a fancy (and possibly intrusive) extension like DarkReader?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript does the trick.

Add a bookmark on your Bookmarks Toolbar, name it "DarkMode" and place this code in URL field

```
javascript:(function() {   const body = document.body;   const isDark = body.classList.contains('dark');    if (isDark) {     body.classList.remove('dark');     body.parentElement.style = '';   } else {     body.classList.add('dark');     body.parentElement.style = 'filter: grayscale(1) invert(1) contrast(0.8)';   } })();
```

Comment: The user will need to press it for every new screen.

Answer (score 0):

The method for built-in dark mode varies between browsers.

**Chrome**

Chrome doesn't offer an official dark mode in the desktop app,
so one needs to use an extension.

**Microsoft Edge**

Although based on Chromium, it has a built-in dark mode.

It uses the system theme by default, but you can also change it
manually using the three-dot menu and going to *Settings > Appearance*
and choosing "Dark" under "Overall appearance".
You may pick a color theme to further customize the browser's top menu bar.

**Firefox**

- Use the hamburger menu to select *Settings > Extensions & Themes*
- Click "Themes" to open the "Manage Your Themes" page
- Select a theme such as "Dark".
  To find additional themes, click "Find more themes" at the bottom
  of the page.

**Safari**

No dark mode, so you'll have to rely on the default system theme.

Reference :
[Blackout: How to Enable Dark Mode on Your Browser](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-enable-dark-mode-on-your-browser).